# Implementing std::array-like constructors in other classes

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, variadic-templates

In all the modern C++ compilers I've worked with, the following is legal:

```
std::array<float, 4> a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

I'm trying to make my own class that has similar construction semantics, but I'm running into an annoying problem. Consider the following attempt:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

template<std::size_t n>
class float_vec
{
private:
  std::array<float, n> underlying_array;

public:
  template<typename... Types>
  float_vec(Types... args)
    : underlying_array{{args...}}
  {
  }
};

int main()
{
  float_vec<4> v = {1, 2, 3, 4}; // error here
}
```

When using int literals like above, the compiler complains it can't implicitly convert `int` to `float`. I think it works in the `std::array` example, though, because the values given are compile-time constants known to be within the domain of `float`. Here, on the other hand, the variadic template uses `int` for the parameter types and the conversion happens within the constructor's initializer list where the values aren't known at compile-time.

I don't want to do an explicit cast in the constructor since that would then allow for all numeric values even if they can't be represented by `float`.

The only way I can think of to get what I want is to somehow have a variable number of parameters, but of a specific type (in this case, I'd want `float`). I'm aware of `std::initializer_list`, but I'd like to be able to enforce the number of parameters at compile time as well.

Any ideas? Is what I want even possible with C++11? Anything new proposed for C++14 that will solve this?

Comment: Well, in C++14, the `size()` function for `std::initializer_list` will be `constexpr`.

Comment: I assume that making your class an aggregate is out of the question?

Comment: OP just needs to update their compiler: http://ideone.com/KOzMcz
As you can see, it works. Their code works out of the box. OP, get Mingw-Builds 4.8.1 if on Windows or g++ 4.8.1 on Linux.

Comment: `float_vec(std::array<float, n> p)
    : underlying_array( std::move(p) )
  {}` would work, but requires double/triple braces as well as a copy/move of the array parameter.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames clang++3.5: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5c4a7d596ed2da9 [dcl.init.aggr]/2 "If the *initializer-clause* is an expression
and a narrowing conversion is required to convert the expression, the program is ill-formed." IIRC g++ treats narrowing conversions only as warnings.

Comment: @dyp http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0f5fa913950f6ef  It is just the same as in OpenGL.. You need to explicitly specify at least one or all values as a float using `0.0f` numerical notation when using `initializer_lists` or `variadic templates`.. Only problem is numbers like 1.5f seems to get narrowed to 1 in clang but not in gcc.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames I think the question is "how to change the class so that the example in `main` compiles?"

Comment: @dyp Yes, that's correct

Comment: @chris That sounds helpful. How would I then use that? `static_assert` in the constructor body?

Comment: @JoBates Make the ctor `constexpr`, and throw an exception if the `size` doesn't match. If a throw happens in the evaluation of a constant expression, the program is ill-formed (=> compile-time error). This would require calling the ctor in a context where a constant expression is required.

Comment: @Casey In the full code I have several more constructors as well, so no, I don't want it to be an aggregate.

Comment: @JoBates It is also possible to achieve the following syntax and allow these kind of conversions (while rejecting narrowing conversions): `auto v = foo<4>::float_vec{1,2,3,4};`

Comment: @dyp Any way to have one constexpr ctor as you describe and one not constexpr so I could, for example, still accept runtime float variables as arguments?

Comment: What's the problem with a `constexpr` ctor accepting runtime values? (I described too many ctors here to know which you're referring to o.O)

Comment: @dyp "This would require calling the ctor in a context where a constant expression is required." I thought you meant only constants would work as arguments. In the variable case, though, would an exception then be thrown at runtime instead of compile time if the number of values was incorrect?

Comment: Yes. But I'd guess you'll rarely have expressions of type `std::initializer_list` that are *not* constant expressions. They'd need to be passed through a (non-constexpr) function, ternary operator involving a runtime-only expression, ..

Comment: Actually, I withdraw that remark. The *constructor* has to appear in a context where a constant expression is required. It doesn't care it the `std::initializer_list` is a constant expression. (Your statement is still correct: an exception will be thrown at runtime if the number of arguments is not correct and the construction is not in a context where a constant expression is required.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little trick is to use constructor inheritance. Just make your class derive from another class which has a pack of the parameters you want.

```
template <class T, std::size_t N, class Seq = repeat_types<N, T>>
struct _array_impl;

template <class T, std::size_t N, class... Seq>
struct _array_impl<T, N, type_sequence<Seq...>>
{
    _array_impl(Seq... elements) : _data{elements...} {}
    const T& operator[](std::size_t i) const { return _data[i]; }

    T _data[N];
};


template <class T, std::size_t N>
struct array : _array_impl<T, N>
{
    using _array_impl<T, N>::_array_impl;
};

int main() {
    array<float, 4> a {1, 2, 3, 4};
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a sample implementation of the repeat_types utility. This sample uses logarithmic template recursion, which is a little less intuitive to implement than with linear recursion.

```
template <class... T>
struct type_sequence
{
    static constexpr inline std::size_t size() noexcept { return sizeof...(T); }
};


template <class, class>
struct _concatenate_sequences_impl;
template <class... T, class... U>
struct _concatenate_sequences_impl<type_sequence<T...>, type_sequence<U...>>
    { using type = type_sequence<T..., U...>; };
template <class T, class U>
using concatenate_sequences = typename _concatenate_sequences_impl<T, U>::type;


template <std::size_t N, class T>
struct _repeat_sequence_impl
    { using type = concatenate_sequences<
        typename _repeat_sequence_impl<N/2, T>::type,
        typename _repeat_sequence_impl<N - N/2, T>::type>; };
template <class T>
struct _repeat_sequence_impl<1, T>
    { using type = T; };
template <class... T>
struct _repeat_sequence_impl<0, type_sequence<T...>>
    { using type = type_sequence<>; };
template <std::size_t N, class... T>
using repeat_types = typename _repeat_sequence_impl<N, type_sequence<T...>>::type;
```

Comment: Using inheriting ctors is a great idea! +1 -- Instead of repeating the types, you can also use indices and a template alias to unpack them as a list of types: `template<class T, int N> using identity_discard = T;` for some indices `indices_seq<Is...>` you can then write `_array_impl(identity_discard<T,Is>...)`. The indices generator will be provided in C++1y by the StdLib and the instantiations can be reused to expand different types.

Answer (score 3):

First of what you are seeing is the [default aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). It has been around since the earliest K&R C. If your type is an aggregate, it supports aggregate initialization already. Also, your example will most likely compile, but the correct way to initialize it is `std::array<int, 3> x ={{1, 2, 3}};` (note the double braces).

What has been added in C++11 is the [initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) construct which requires a bit of compiler magic to be implemented.

So, what you can do now is add constructors and assignment operators that accept a value of `std::initializer_list` and this will offer the same syntax for your type.

Example:

```
#include <initializer_list>

struct X {
  X(std::initializer_list<int>) {
    // do stuff
  }
};

int main()
{
  X x = {1, 2, 3};

  return 0;
}
```

Why does your current approach not work? Because in C++11 `std::initializer_list::size` is not a `constexpr` or part of the `initializer_list` type. You cannot use it as a template parameter.

A few possible hacks: make your type an aggregate.

```
#include <array>

template<std::size_t N>
struct X {
  std::array<int, N> x;
};

int main()
{
  X<3> x = {{{1, 2, 3}}}; // triple braces required
  return 0;
}
```

Provide a `make_*` function to deduce the number of arguments:

```
#include <array>

template<std::size_t N>
struct X {
  std::array<int, N> x;
};

template<typename... T>
auto make_X(T... args) -> X<sizeof...(T)>
// might want to find the common_type of the argument pack as well
{ return X<sizeof...(T)>{{{args...}}}; } 

int main()
{
  auto x = make_X(1, 2, 3);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: consider to use perfect forwarding and universal references in your `make_X()` function template.

Comment: @Manu343726 Definitely. I thought it was obvious that this should be a proto-type and not a production quality implementation.

Comment: "the correct way to initialize it is `std::array<int, 3> x ={{1, 2, 3}};`". The standard actually only mentions the single-brace version. From N3337 23.3.2.1.2: "An array is an aggregate that can be initialized with the syntax
`array<T, N> a = { initializer-list };`
where initializer-list is a comma-separated list of up to N elements whose types are convertible to T."

Comment: @JoBates You are correct. As far as I can tell this is a C++14 feature, because earlier versions would not allow the brace omission.

Comment: @pmr C++11 allows brace elision only for `type X = {..}` but not for `type X {..}`. See [CWG 1270](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1270)

Answer (score 1):

If you use several braces to initialize the instance, you can leverage list-init of another type to accept these conversions for compile-time constants. Here's a version that uses a raw array, so you only need parens + braces for construction:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

template<int... Is> struct seq {};
template<int N, int... Is> struct gen_seq : gen_seq<N-1, N-1, Is...> {};
template<int... Is> struct gen_seq<0, Is...> : seq<Is...> {};

template<std::size_t n>
class float_vec
{
private:
  std::array<float, n> underlying_array;

  template<int... Is>
  constexpr float_vec(float const(&arr)[n], seq<Is...>)
    : underlying_array{{arr[Is]...}}
  {}

public:
  constexpr float_vec(float const(&arr)[n])
    : float_vec(arr, gen_seq<n>{})
  {}
};

int main()
{
  float_vec<4> v0 ({1, 2, 3, 4});   // fine
  float_vec<4> v1 {{1, 2, 3, 4}};   // fine
  float_vec<4> v2 = {{1, 2, 3, 4}}; // fine
}
```

Comment: This is pretty crazy. I would have never thought to use a variadic template to generate indices like that.

Comment: @JoBates The `seq` and `gen_seq` are *not* my invention. It's a "common technique" to expand something related to variadic templates (e.g. for expanding the members of a tuple as function arguments).

Answer (score -1):

Explicitly specify that the data type for the initialization to floating point type. You can do this by doing "1.0f" instead of putting "1". If it is a double, put "1.0d". If it is a long, put "1l" and for unsigned long put "1ul" and so on..

I've tested it here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/396f5d418cbd3f14
and here: http://ideone.com/ZLiMhg

Your code was fine. You just initialized the class a bit incorrect.

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t n>
class float_vec
{
private:
  std::array<float, n> underlying_array;

public:
  template<typename... Types>
  float_vec(Types... args)
    : underlying_array{{args...}}
  {
  }

  float get(int index) {return underlying_array[index];}
};

int main()
{
  float_vec<4> v = {1.5f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.5f}; //works fine now..

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    std::cout<<v.get(i)<<" ";
}
```

Comment: I believe the OP's goal is explicitly to allow the integer syntax.